# PHP : Can not go into my callback function in my usort for an array of object

Tags: php, usort

I am a beginner in php and I can't figure out how to sort an array of objects.
I wanted to use usort, but I don't even go on my callback function and I don't realy get why.
Here is my array that I get after parsing an xml file :

```
[
    {
        "hometeam": {
            "name": "Team1",
            "id": "1"
        },
        "awayteam": {
            "name": "Team2",
            "id": "2"
        },
        "date": "2.02.2021",
        "time": "7:00 PM",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "hometeam": {
            "name": "Team3",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "awayteam": {
            "name": "Team4",
            "id": "4"
        },
        "date": "2.02.2021",
        "time": "7:30 PM",
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "hometeam": {
            "name": "Team5",
            "id": "5"
        },
        "awayteam": {
            "name": "Team6",
            "id": "6"
        },
        "date": "2.02.2021",
        "time": "6:30 PM",
        "id": "3"
    }
]
```

Which is stored in $matchs
Then I call

```
usort($matchs, "orderByDate");
```

where "orderByDate" is my sort function defined like this :

```
public function orderByDate($game1, $game2)
    {
        return strtotime($game1['time']) - strtotime($game2['time']);
    }
```

I don't even know if this orderByDate is working as I never go into it and I don't understand why.
Can someone provide me an explanation please ?

Comment: Try this: usort($matchs, function($game1, $game2){
       return strtotime($game1['time']) - strtotime($game2['time']);
});

Comment: Thanks, i worked well (sorry for the time to answer)